# dprintf in Cpython

Tags: python, c, cpython

I want to check the log printed by `dprintf` in Cpython such as [this one](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/thread_pthread.h#L315), but there is only one parameter for `dprintf` here, how to check those logs? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a release version of Python, the `dprintf`s are stripped, and there is no logging by these statements. It is not possible to see the output from them.

`dprintf` is a macro that is actually only defined in [`thread.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/thread.c#L46). The definition is

```
#ifdef Py_DEBUG
static int thread_debug = 0;
#define dprintf(args)   (void)((thread_debug & 1) && printf args)
#define d2printf(args)  ((thread_debug & 8) && printf args)
#else
#define dprintf(args)
#define d2printf(args)
#endif
```

i.e. *if* `Py_DEBUG` is set **and** `thread_debug & 1`, then the log is printed using `printf`, to standard output. For this you would need a debug build of Python. Iff you have a debug build, the value of `thread_debug` can be controlled with the environment variable [`PYTHONTHREADDEBUG`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/thread.c#L59):

```
void
PyThread_init_thread(void)
{
#ifdef Py_DEBUG
    char *p = Py_GETENV("PYTHONTHREADDEBUG");

    if (p) {
        if (*p)
            thread_debug = atoi(p);
        else
            thread_debug = 1;
    }
#endif /* Py_DEBUG */
    if (initialized)
        return;
    initialized = 1;
    dprintf(("PyThread_init_thread called\n"));
    PyThread__init_thread();
}
```

i.e. the variable must be present for the variable set to a value of `1`, and if set to for example 9, this would enable both `dprintf` and `d2printf`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to recompile Python to see those. When configuring, give the `--with-pydebug` option. It should come out on standard out. You may also need to set the environment variable PYTHONTHREADDEBUG to 1, but that shouldn't be nessesary.

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#debug-mode-variables